# Why does GCC C89/C90 ANSI C use __STDC_VERSION__ in Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, c89, ansi-c

I need to confirm my code if I'm using ANSI C (C89/C90) and I notice this:

[image]

Even if I have selected ASNI C (C89/C90) standard in Eclipse CDT.

[image]

**Question:**

It is told that ANSI C does not use `__STDC_VERSION__` but why do I see the same value for `__STDC_VERSION__` as `199901L` for C99 standard in Eclipse CDT?

I'm using GCC compiler for Lubuntu Linux.

Comment: *This macro expands to the C Standard's version number, a long integer constant of the form yyyymmL where yyyy and mm are the year and month of the Standard version. This signifies which version of the C Standard the compiler conforms to. Like __STDC__, this is not necessarily accurate for the entire implementation, unless GNU CPP is being used with GCC.

The value 199409L signifies the 1989 C standard as amended in 1994, which is the current default; the value 199901L signifies the 1999 revision of the C standard.*

Comment: @0___________ and why does STDC version show 199901L when I selected C89?

Comment: The `__STDC_VERSION__` macro was added to C94 (Amendment 1); it was not part of C89/C90, so it won't be set by a compiler that faithfully follows the C89/C90 standard.  There's no good reason to be using C89/C90 these days.  You should be using C11 or C18 (C17).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I understand, but I'm not using C99 standard
 I'm using C89/C90 standard as you see.

Comment: @euraad Although this does not answer your question, have you tried with the `-traditional` flag?

Comment: It's hard for me to guess what Eclipse CDT is doing — I don't have it installed anywhere.  At the command line, on my Mac, using `-std=c90` causes the compilation to fail because there are C++-style comments in `<stdio.h>`.  On a Linux machine, I got zero as the output from: `#include <stdio.h>` /
`int main(void) {` /
`#ifndef __STDC_VERSION__` /
`#define __STDC_VERSION__ 0L` /
`#endif` / 
`printf("%ld\n", __STDC_VERSION__); return 0; }` (file `stdc13.c` compiled using `gcc -std=c90 -o stdc13 stdcs13.c`).  Have you compiled and run the code?  Is the GUI misleading you?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it might be a bug in Eclipse CDT?

Comment: Yes, it might be a bug (feature?) in Eclipse CDT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested it. Eclipse CDT simply shows the oldest value programmed. It does not have anything in common with the actual `__STDC_VALUE__` seen by the compiler.

When you compile as C90 `__STDC_VALUE__` is not defined and value shown in the Eclipse is not valid. I believe that it is an Eclipse bug.

Colouring is also wrong.

[image]

Comment: Yes! It's a bug in Eclipse! The code is working. But the GUI is missleadning. Thank you for your answer.